# How to check datatypes of columns in SQL - using jupyter notebook custom dataset

Tags: python, mysql, sql, jupyter-notebook

I'm practicing SQL in jupyter notebook with a dataset I created within the notebook.

When I create the dataset, I know I am selecting the datatypes per column. However, I want to double check the data types as I work through the problems.

Here is my custom dataset I created within Jupyter Notebook

```
%load_ext sql
%%sql sqlite://


%%sql
CREATE TABLE orders(created_at DATE, 
                   customer_id varchar(50), order_id varchar(50),
                   units INT(10),
                   sales INT(10));
INSERT INTO orders VALUES('2020-22-01', 'A', 'X', 7, 150);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES('2020-12-01', 'B', 'Y', 5, 222);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES('2020-01-01', 'C', 'Z', 6, 340);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES('2020-13-01', 'B', 'D', 5, 163);
```

What is the correct way to get the datatypes of each column if I made the dataframe within the notebook?

When I use `SELECT DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` I get the error:

```
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
[SQL: SELECT DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Comment: You have tagged MySQL but the error says  sqlite3 , which one are you really using ?

Comment: `select DATA_TYPE  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` works fine in MySQL, even though probably you need to include TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME and COLUMN_NAME to identify the columns